# Making a local repo to a public repo?

Tags: linux, git

I have a local git repo on my Linux box, that I now would like to put on a public git host.

From what I can read the procedure should be

- create the public repo
- clone the empty public repo to desktop
- add local git repo as additional remote in the clone
- update the remote
- merge remotes//master
- push master to origin
- remove the additional remote created earlier

This should transfer the commit log as well, from my understanding?

**Question**

Can someone give a command example of this, if the public repo is `git.example.com/new` and the local is called `old`?

Comment: Do you want to put your repo on github or bitbucket? If yes, use their import facilities - couple of clicks and you'll be done

Comment: The public git repo is a pirvate hosted one.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's private or public, the question is do they have a similar import facility as github or bitbucket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you just need to a add a remote

```
cd old
git remote add origin git@github.com:antirez/redis.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: For most git hosting services, you should still create the public repo first, then you can add it as remote and push (probably `push -u`).